# What is that Root[...] inside the answer represent?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

[image]

So I am encountering this situation, in which  mathematica doesn't give me the answer, but in a form of "Root". How do I interpret this ? what is the number after the "&" represent?
How should I ask mathematica to evaluate this Root for me?

Please don't tell me to use `N[%]`. I have an equation of 4 variables and I don't have numerical value for them. I would like it in symbolic form.

Comment: Have you searched for `Root` in the documentation?

Comment: Yes.From the website, it says "Root[..]-represents the exact k^(th) root of the polynomial equation", however, if you look at the term for x, the heighest power is 5, and k=1.  So doesn't represent the 1st root ?

Comment: A polynomial of degree 5 has up to five roots. $k=1$ means take the first one. For example, `Root[#^2 - 100 &, 1]` is $-10$, and `Root[#^2 - 100, 2]` is $10$.